# Unitization of stable $C^*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a stable $C^*$-algebra,is the unitization of $A$ also stable?If not,can anyone show me some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for any $C^*$-algebras $A$ and $B$ and any tensor product $A\otimes B$, we have $A\otimes B$ is unital if and only if both $A$ and $B$ are unital.  Since the algebra $\mathcal K$ of compact operators on a separable Hilbert space is non-unital, it follows that any stable $C^*$-algebra is non-unital, and therefore the unitization of any $C^*$-algebra is non-stable.

Comment: Thanks so much!May I ask you another question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483451/definition-of-index-map-in-the-context-of-c-algebras